# Wayland : Window positionning fails with PyQt and Libroffice ? How to fix this issue?

Tags: libreoffice, window, wayland, pyqt

I use LibreOffice and PyQt for small applications.

In Libreoffice .setPosSize is inoperative

```
`With oForm.CurrentController.Frame
    .ContainerWindow.isMaximized = False
    .ContainerWindow.setPosSize(150,150,200,600,15)
End With
```

In PyQt setGeometry is inoperative

```
    wMain =QWidget()    
    self.setCentralWidget(wMain)
    self.setGeometry(120,150,1000,400)
```

Someone can help me?

thank a lot

Ubuntu 23.10  LibreOffice 6.7.2.1

Comment: What are you trying to resize? For example, here is a discussion about how to resize a form in Base: https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/how-to-customize-base-for-window-size/65603.

Comment: Sorry, **resize** is operative but no **positionning** <br/>

Comment: It is Wayland who **does not position ** the window.X11 does the job

Comment: Sorry, but i think that Wayland and also  Libreoffice (ubuntu 23.10) don't like my too old graphic card
Intel® HD Graphics 4000 (IVB GT2)
For Python with Xorg is good, not for Libreoffice.